# cannt implicitly convert int to bool

Tags: c#, while-loop

The problem is with line 19. i thought it was the while statement but just noticed its line 19. I've tried various things and i can't find the solution to my error.

```
using System;

class MainClass {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {
      Random r = new Random();
      int Randomnum= r.Next(0,100);
      int x = 0;

      while(x != Randomnum){
          x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); 

          if (x < Randomnum)
          Console.WriteLine("higher");

          if (x > Randomnum)
          Console.WriteLine("lower");
       
          if (x = Randomnum)
          Console.WriteLine("corrct!");
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Last conditional has a single `=` (assignment) instead of double `==` (comparison)

Comment: `corrct` -> `correct`, sorry.

Comment: its fine! i didn't notice that myself, thanks. i don'r understand why one 19 is being weird though. the other 2 if statements work fine but not if x = randomnum :/

Comment: @OliverSharp because `x = Randomnum` is an assignment. And an assignment in c# always returns the assigned value. In your case an integer, which cannot be used as condition in an `if` clause. You want `x == Randomnum` (double ==) which is the operator for comparison

Answer (score 2):

Looks like  you have a syntax issue like Nauman mentioned.  The Equality Operator (==)  is the comparison operator, checking if their operands are equal or not and the Equals(=) compares the contents of a string. The == Operator compares the reference identity while the = method compares only contents.

Change if `(x = Randomnum)` to if `(x == Randomnum)` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Its syntax issue
if (x = Randomnum)
use double equal for comparison
if (x == Randomnum)
single equal is for assignment that's why if condition doesn't receive bool value and its showing this error.